# SwiftUI Image clipped to shape has transparent padding in context menu

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

In my SwiftUI app, I have an image in my asset catalog with an aspect ratio of 1:1. In my code, I have an `Image` view with a different aspect ratio that clips the image to the new size:

```swift
Image("My Image")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
    .clipped()
```

[image: image clipped to aspect ratio]

But when I attach a context menu to this image (with the `contextMenu` modifier), the original aspect ratio is still there, but with transparent padding:

[image: image clipped to aspect ratio with context menu]

How do I keep the image clipped to the new frame inside the context menu, so there's no padding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe the correct solution that will work in all scenarios is to set the first argument (kind) in the contentShape:

```
func contentShape<S>(_ kind: ContentShapeKinds, _ shape: S)
```

Set that to .contextMenuPreview and this will work for all shapes:

```
Image("leaf")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
    .clipShape(Circle())
    .contentShape(ContentShapeKinds.contextMenuPreview, Circle())
    .contextMenu {
        Text("Menu Item")
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

On iOS 15, please see the [accepted post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69968151/5569234). This solution works on iOS 14.

---

I was able to solve this by adding a `.contentShape(Rectangle())` modifier to the image:

```swift
Image("My Image")
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(width: 300, height: 250)
    .clipped()
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .contextMenu {
        Text("Menu Item")
    }
```

[image: image clipped to aspect ratio with context menu - correct behavior]

Comment: This was such a beautiful solution. I was able to use content shape to change the context menu preview to Circle() as well. Thanks!

Comment: yip, this question and answer is still useful. helped me, thanks

Comment: I don't believe this solution is working in iOS 15.  Haven't tried it before that.  If you use a Circle shape you will see it doesn't work.  And in your code if you remove contentShape on iOS 15 it doesn't make any difference.  I wonder if anybody can make this work with a shape that is not rectangular.

Comment: @alionthego You're right, they updated the `contentShape` API on iOS 15. I just accepted your answer, thanks for sharing!