# SwiftUI. Square shadow around a circular image when using the context menu

Tags: swiftui, contextmenu, shadow

In my application, I am using a circular image with a drop shadow as a context menu button.

Code:

```
    Image(systemName: "plus")
        .padding(20)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .shadow(radius: 10)
        .contextMenu{
            Button {} label: {
                Label("test", systemImage: "")
            }
        }
```

Result:

[image: result]

When the context menu is invoked, the shadow becomes square ((

[image: problem]

Can I fix this somehow?

Comment: It is not a shadow it is *menu* itself, it is square and not transparent.

Comment: Yes, I understand something like that. The question is, is it possible to somehow set the shape of the interface element so that the menu respects it in its own animation?

Comment: It is solvable issue, not a big deal, need some playing with code. Try overly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here: [SwiftUI Image clipped to shape has transparent padding in context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687224/swiftui-image-clipped-to-shape-has-transparent-padding-in-context-menu) . In my case I need to add the modifier `.contentShape(Circle())` to Image().
Final correct code:

```swift
Image(systemName: "plus")
    .padding(20)
    .background(Color.yellow)
    .clipShape(Circle())
    .shadow(radius: 10)
    .contentShape(Circle()) //here
    .contextMenu {
        Button {} label: {
            Label("test", systemImage: "")
        }
    }
```